# Vista 32 Stop Error 0x000000B4: Video Driver Failed to Initialize. Is there hope?

Tags: windows-vista, bsod, 32-bit

Looking around on th internets, it's looking like the only option I have left is format and reinstall, which is something I'm **REALLY** trying to avoid.  The machine has alot of activated software from a couple of years ago (a couple thousand dollars invested), and don't have all the documentation for it.  **Why Vista?  Well at the time, there wasn't support for Windows 7 with Pro Tools 8 LE and most of it's plugins.**

How it started was when I started Windows, it automatically went to `chkdsk`, which didn't alarm me at first (seen it do this every once in while).  Sitll, I can't think of anything that prompt it to start `chkdsk` in the first place, ie, the computer didn't get shut down properly.  Then I see a bunch of "Deleting Index Entry XXXX" flying down the screen.  Thats when I started to get worried.  When `chkdsk` finished doing it's thing, the Windows loading screen appear as normal.  Then, right before windows login screen would appear (no mouse at this point), I get the BSOD.

- I tried every safe mode option available: BSOD.
- I tried running chkdsk again: it did do some additional repairs with several "Found orpaned files".  Still BSOD.
- I tried automatic repair and system restore from both the system and the Windows Vista Boot disk repair menu: BSOD
- Located and replaced with known set of working video drivers (Geforce 9500m gs): BSOD

I am quite certain that this isn't a hardware issue becuase it's dual boot computer with Windows 7 64, and comes up no problem.  In fact, I used the Windows 7 installation to replace the known working drivers.  This has got to be an OS related issue.  **Am I out of options?**

Comment: For context: [Bug Check 0xB4: VIDEO_DRIVER_INIT_FAILURE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560133(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Looks like I've covered everything in the document :(

Comment: This is just an idea, but maybe you'll want to generate a VHD from the volume of your broken OS using [Disk2VHD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx) from your working OS. Then you can mount that image and mess with it all you want without further breaking your real installation.

Comment: Vista and Hope in the same sentence, now that is funny.